# using std::visit with specialization of a deleted function

Tags: c++, variant

I am trying to parse a string generically based on some prior knowledge.
str is passed to convert() with overloads for the types I want to support, and try to use std::visit() to call the right overload:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
#include <charconv>

template <class ...Request, class ...Types>
constexpr bool holdsAlternative(const std::variant<Types...>& v) noexcept
{
   return (std::holds_alternative<Request>(v) || ...);
}
template <typename T>
T convert(const std::string &str) = delete;

template <>
float convert<float>(const std::string &str)
{
    float result = 0;
    std::from_chars(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), result);
    return result;
}
template <>
int32_t convert<int32_t >(const std::string &str)
{
    int32_t result = 0;
    std::from_chars(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), result);
    return result;
}
using data_type = std::variant<int32_t, float, std::string>;
std::vector<data_type> Types {float{}, int32_t{}, std::string{}};
int main()
{
    std::string str{"123"};
    bool r = holdsAlternative<int32_t, float>(Types[1]);
    if (r)
    {
       std::visit([&](auto &t) { return convert<decltype(t)>(str); }, Types[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what do you want to happen when `convert` encounters a string? `std::visit` must have a case for every variant possibility, so deleting one of the cases makes little sense.

Comment: I thought of this approach.. not compiling though!

Comment: I don't mind similar approach though

Answer (score 2):

There are three issues with your code:

1. The visitor must be applicable to all possible variants, so deleting the non-specialized `convert` won't work. You can however have the non-specialized version throw a runtime exception.
2. The visitor passed to `std::visit` must have the same return type for all variants. If this is an issue for you depends on what you want to do. If you want to set the variant value by the output of `convert`, you are fine: The visitors could all return `void`.
3. You should pass `std::decay_t<decltype(t)>` as the template parameter in the visitor, because `decltype(t)` would otherwise be deduced as a reference, and you don't have specializations for e.g. `float&`.

Here is the fixed code: https://godbolt.org/z/abqv6xKde

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
#include <charconv>

template <class ...Request, class ...Types>
constexpr bool holdsAlternative(const std::variant<Types...>& v) noexcept
{
   return (std::holds_alternative<Request>(v) || ...);
}

template <typename T>
T convert(const std::string &str){
    throw std::logic_error("Conversion not supported\n");
};

template <>
float convert<float>(const std::string &str)
{
    std::cout << "float\n";
    float result = 0;
    std::from_chars(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), result);
    return result;
}
template <>
int32_t convert<int32_t >(const std::string &str)
{
    std::cout << "int32_t\n";
    int32_t result = 0;
    std::from_chars(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), result);
    return result;
}

using data_type = std::variant<int32_t, float, std::string>;

std::vector<data_type> Types {float{}, int32_t{}, std::string{}};

int main()
{
    std::string str{"123"};
    bool r = holdsAlternative<int32_t, float>(Types[1]);
    if (r)
    {
       std::visit([&](auto &t) { t = convert<std::decay_t<decltype(t)>>(str); }, Types[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank your for your time, indeed it works, didn't know about std::decay_t

Comment: @joegrech, I posted the whole code here, including your part, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/283777/c-minimal-csv-parser-cut2